# ListTile Components displacing when used with Dismissible Widget - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dismissible, flutter-list-tile

ListTile components are displaing whenever it is not being dragged to the full extent for Dismissal.
Please look at the photos to understand the bug better

[image]
[image]
[image]

code for `home_view.dart`:

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String id = '/';

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          Constants.riders,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2.5,
            // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 4),
        child: Consumer<HomeViewModel>(
            builder: (_, model, __) => model.riders.isNotEmpty
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (_, index) => Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2),
                      child: Dismissible(
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          onDismissed: (direction) {
                            model.removeRider(model.riders[index]);
                            if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                              showSuccessSnackbar(
                                  Constants.approveRider, context);
                            } else {
                              showErrorSnackbar(Constants.rejectRider, context);
                            }
                          },
                          background: Container(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 2),
                                child: Text(
                                  Constants.approve,
                                  style: bodyTextStyle3,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          secondaryBackground: Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    right: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 2),
                                child: Text(
                                  Constants.reject,
                                  style: bodyTextStyle3,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: RiderTile(rider: model.riders[index])),
                    ),
                    itemCount: model.riders.length,
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: Text(
                      Constants.noRiders,
                      style: bodyTextStyle1,
                    ),
                  )),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: RectangularFAB(
        text: Constants.add,
        onPress: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AddRiderView.id);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

code for `RiderTile`:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RiderView.id, arguments: widget.rider);
      },
      leading: widget.rider.photo == null
          ? const CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/rider.png'))
          : CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: FileImage(widget.rider.photo!),
            ),
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
      title: Text(widget.rider.name, style: bodyTextStyle1),
      subtitle: Text(widget.rider.phone),
    );
```

Can someone please help me understand as to why such an error is occurring and how I can fix it?